# i can't find ''close'' ''maximise'' minimise'' in opened tabs

Tags: raspberry-pi-desktop

Please, here is my problem, I use VNC Viewer on my laptop to have access to my py 4 modelB. buti can't find ''close'' ''maximise'' minimise'' in opened tabs. I tried many OS but without any success.

thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: what do those **windows** look like when you use the pi4 directly?

Comment: That looks like Raspberry Pi OS 32bit Bullseye? Is it fully updated?

Comment: I didn't use it directly yet, because I don't have a monitor for the moment. for the versions available in the website are based Based on Debian (bullseye). I don't know where to download another operating system. https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/operating-systems/#raspberry-pi-desktop

Comment: What's missing there isn't just those buttons -- notice where you have indicated they should be is not where they actually are when they are there.  They are just above that on the end of a titlebar, which is not there either, nor are the frames.  Those are provided by the *window manager* (`openbox`) using features of the ("windowing") Xorg server.   I've noticed before people complaining sometimes this doesn't work correctly with some VNC clients.   The fact that the problem is there "with many OS" is probably because all of them use Xorg (and many of them likely openbox as well).

Answer (score 0):

In my case it went away after enabling VNC on Interface options and rebooting

Comment: Surely if VNC wasn't enabled, you woildn't get a window displayed at all.

Comment: And what has it to do with that Max/min button is missing?

Answer (score 0):

Preferences → Appearance Settings, then in Defaults tab

use this method